# How to get leads details in SalesForce with the REST API?

Tags: rest, api, salesforce, lead

Is it possible, with the REST API available from SalesForce, to get the list of all leads and all their details?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can, with the help of SOQL queries.

Read here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm

Example: POST https://instance_name.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/query?q=SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName FROM Lead

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.